# What is the issue when autologin using PHP and Javascripts to my site?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, curl, drupal-7

> > Using Javascript

```
var username = "user1";
var password = "user1";
jQuery.ajax({ 
    url : "http://domainname.com/rest/user/login.json",
    type : 'post', 
    data : 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password), 
    dataType : 'json', 
    error : function(data) { console.log("error"); console.error(data); }, 
    success : function(data) { console.log("success"); console.info(data); } 
});
```

> > Using PHP/Curl

```
// Method: POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data: array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    return curl_exec($curl);
}

// Example
$method = "POST";
$url = "http://domainname.com/rest/user/login.json";
$rurl = "http://domainname.com/";
$postdata = array('username'=>'editor1', 'password'=>'editor1');
$response = CallAPI($method, $url, $postdata );

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
```

Result:

```
{"sessid":"R03y8-40VBh6FDEIfi9Lnm2kh2SikCxY3105egCynDY","session_name":"SESS2063f746500d52bace78ba433478bd2d","user": ......
```

I am trying to get login using two different scripts one from JQuery and Second From PHP/Curl.

When I fire JQuery it is autologin sucessully working.
But, When I try to autologin from PHP/Curl it will give me success response as above but when open URL Will not logged in can any one explain what was the issue.

As per my assumption it could be possible that Session_name/Sessid may be store in cookies?

Answer (score 1):

> As per my assumption it could be possible that Session_name/Sessid may be store in cookies?

As many other engines, Drupal requires session cooke, looks like SESSa89ab839dd1casdasdec163e12679c2f2ea1e=asdfasdf2323423dsa . Set this cookie (like session_name=sessid) in php with setcookie (http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and send response to the client.

> l. My question is, when we use jQuery instread of PHP/CURL it is automatically add cookie value to browser?

When Jquery sends query to the server, browser gets response with the Set-Cookie header, you can check this using chrome developer tools (or similar utility of your browser).

When you execute your PHP code on the server side PHP does nothing with the response cookies, because PHP interpretator is a not browser.

Look at this dummy query scheme:

1) Jquery
WebBrowser => Apacher/PHP server (login.json code)
Apacher/PHP server => Browser (response with the session cookie)

2) Login on the php side
Web Browser =>  Apacher/PHP server (your script)
Apacher/PHP server => Apacher/PHP (call to the login code)
Apacher/PHP server => Apacher/PHP server (response of the login code to the first script)

---

Here cookie information is lost, because it's just http query in the php code and nothing more. No headers are automatically set. You need to set this cookie manually with setkookie() function or $_COOKIE variable.

---

Apacher/PHP server => Web Browser (with all cookies you set int the current script)

Sorry for my grammar, hope i helped you.

Comment: Above code is working fine when I am passing username and password to user/login.json url.

My question is, when we use jQuery instread of PHP/CURL it is automatically add cookie value to browser?

In my case the above code is working fine and login me to site successfully.

But, When I am using the same using PHP/CURL Request it will give me success response with Sess ID and Value but I think not stored as Cookie and do not logged in me to site?

Any Help

Comment: Comment was too long, i had to change an answer.